# How to use the 3DES/Authentication sector in MifareUltralight C in Android SDK

Tags: android, nfc

I've read through plenty of questions and forums and not found any helpful answers/information for me to achieve the simple task of,

using the Authentication sector which is 3DES capable for a Mifare Ultralight C card using the various classes in Android SDK. Easiest form of communication from Android would be to get an instance of the tag of type MifareUltralight class.

I'm guessing transceivebytes() function is going to be involved in this in some manner but i'm unable to identify it.

Any kind of help/guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC tag communication should not be done on the UI thread, so you need to set up an background thread (e.g. using [`Runnable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)). You pass the NFC Intent from your Activity to that background thread and then do:

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdaptor.EXTRA_TAG);
MifareUltralight ul = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
if(ul == null)
  return; // not MIFARE Ultralight
byte[] authenticateCommand = { ... }; // data for authentication command
byte[] authenticateResponse = ul.transceive(authenticateCommand); // send it
... // etc.
```

The specific details on how to do MIFARE Ultralight C authentication are proprietary and, AFAIK, only available under NDA.

Comment: Thank you, but i actually got this much already working. My problem is related to the proprietary method. I have the MF0ICU2_SDS.pdf file, yet there is no explanation to how it should be handled. Can i write anything into it and will it automatically get encrypted? or am i supposed to encrypt and write it?

Comment: The Short DataSheet (SDS) contains the public information. The details  for the proprietary method can be requested at http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_card_ics/mifare_smart_card_ics/mifare_ultralight/MF0ICU2_SDS.html

Comment: awesome! thank you @NFC guy! do you have an irc room that u sit in or maybe any other place where i can take your assistance? Clearly you are a NFC guru!